# Which screen size should I start making a wireframe from?

Tags: user-interface, responsive-design, user-experience, wireframe, adobe-xd

Usually, browsing on Behance, Dribbble or other online stuff like those, we see wireframes only for desktop or only for mobile, so I'm still in doubt about something: when we need to make a wireframe (and considering the "mobile-first"), where should I start from? Desktop, tablet and mobile or the inverse?

Answer (score 0):

"Mobile first" is a design philosophy of designing for a small screen and touch interactions first and then adding layout changes that need to happen as the display gets larger...

**Start with the size/device your audience is most likely to use for interaction.** Not all interactions are best on a small screen...

So as a designer who knows most users will be on a phone might go: "mobile first". In that case, you should start with mobile wireframes and then show the developers how it should change on a bigger screen by making additional wireframes (if that's your team's process).

Behance and Dribbble are bad examples of process since they're usually only showing you the end result, not the work that goes into getting there.